# vega-lite bar chart stacked colored values

Tags: vega-lite

```
 "data": {"values": [{
                "key": "test1",
                "doc_count": 14,
                "misc": {                       
                    "min": 5,
                    "max": 8,
                    "avg": 6.5                        
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "test2",
                "doc_count": 14,
                "misc": {                        
                    "min": 2,
                    "max": 8,
                    "avg": 4.5                       
                }
            }]}
```

Given this data a need to paint a stacked bar chart with 3 colors per each bar for min.avg and max.
Currently i can not find any solution for this because this is already an aggregation coming from elastic and all examples  i´ve seen for stacked bar chart use the color scale for a fields value but i need the same for 3 fields.

Is it possible with this source data ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by painting 3 colors per bar... do you mean three bars, each of a different color, with height reflecting the min/max/avg?

Comment: No, in this case 2bars test1 and test2.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want the three values/colors to appear on each of the two bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [fold](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) transform to convert data into long format.

`{"fold": ["misc.min", "misc.max","misc.avg"]}`

should work.  If it doesn't work due to nested data, you can use calculate to flatten each field first (e.g., `{"calculate": "misc.min", "as": "min"}) and then fold the flattened fields.